# A calculus question from an econ paper

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

The paper says:

$\int_{[0,\tau]} e^{-(\gamma-\rho)s}d(e^{-\rho s} S_s)=e^{-(\gamma-\rho)\tau}e^{-\rho \tau} S_{\tau}+(\gamma-\rho) \int_{0}^{\tau}e^{-(\gamma-\rho)s}e^{-\rho s} S_s ds$.

where $dS_t=\rho S_tdt+\lambda u_t v dt+di_t-dc_t$. In other words, these are not stochastic integrals.

My understanding is that, if $S_0=0$,

$\int_{[0,\tau]}e^{-(\gamma-\rho)s}d(e^{-\rho s} S_s)=e^{-(\gamma-\rho)\tau}e^{-\rho \tau} S_{\tau}-\rho \int_{0}^{\tau}e^{-(\gamma-\rho)s}e^{-\rho s} S_s ds$.

Where is the term $\gamma \int_{0}^{\tau}e^{-(\gamma-\rho)s}e^{-\rho s} S_s ds$
comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are applying integration by parts to get that expression, getting $$\int udv=uv-\int vdu$$ with $u=e^{-(\gamma-\rho)s}$ and $v=e^{-\rho s}S_s$ the factor of $\gamma-\rho$ specifically comes from the $$du=-(\gamma-\rho) e^{-(\gamma-\rho)s}ds$$ term of the integral.